Frequent Network Error (ConnectionError) During WandB Run Initialization
I am having issue with have WANDB as it disconnect frequently in a non-deterministic manner.
below is the description.
Error Message:
WandB run initialized successfully. Run ID: f782c567-5e34-4544-b7dc-a717e0af18dd, Name: repercussion-24-07-21-01-32-50-536 wandb: Network error (ConnectionError), entering retry loop.
WandB run initialized successfully. Run ID: f782c567-5e34-4544-b7dc-a717e0af18dd, Name: repercussion-24-07-21-01-32-50-536
wandb: Network error (ConnectionError), entering retry loop.
Code Implementation:
import os
import wandb
from tenacity import retry, retry_if_exception_type, stop_after_attempt, wait_fixed

class WandbRun:
    def __init__(self, project: str, entity: str, config: dict = {}, tags: list = [], run_name: str = "", run_id: str = ""):
        self.project = project
        self.entity = entity
        self.config = config
        self.tags = tags
        self.run_name = run_name
        self.run_id = run_id
        self.run = None
        self.initialize_run()

    @retry(
        stop=stop_after_attempt(5),
        wait=wait_fixed(2),
        retry=retry_if_exception_type(ConnectionError),
    )
    def initialize_run(self):
        params = {
            "project": self.project,
            "entity": self.entity,
            "config": self.config,
            "tags": self.tags,
            "resume": "allow",
        }
        if self.run_name:
            params["name"] = self.run_name
        if self.run_id:
            params["id"] = self.run_id
        try:
            self.run = wandb.init(**params)
            print(f"WandB run initialized successfully. Run ID: {self.run.id}, Name: {self.run.name}")
        except (wandb.CommError, ConnectionError) as e:
            print(f"WandB initialization failed: {e}")
            raise
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Unexpected error during WandB initialization: {e}")
            raise

# Usage
run = WandbRun(
    project="my_project",
    entity="my_entity",
    config={"param1": "value1"},
    tags=["tag1", "tag2"],
    run_name="my_run_name"
)

Environment Details:
WandB version: 0.13.7
Python version: 3.10
cloud provider: GCP

Also, I have tried wandb troublshooting guide: https://docs.wandb.ai/guides/technical-faq/troubleshooting#how-do-i-deal-with-network-issues.
any suggestion why this happens or solution is greatly appreciated.
Thanks :)

Are you still experiencing this issue? What type of setup are you running your code from? Is this a distributed setup?
